# trying to print elements's vector of struct in a struct list

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, struct, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

const int n = 20;
```

Defining the structs & list

```
typedef struct pole{
   int year;
   char county[n];
   char ID_election[n];
   char ID_electionUser[n];
   int num_candidates;
   char name_candidate[n]; 
   int limit_votes;
}election;

typedef struct polelist{
   election voting;
   struct polelist *next_pole;
}node_pole;
```

Funtions

```
void createElection(node_pole *head_pole, election *info);
void insertElection(node_pole **head_pole, election *info);
void printElection(node_pole *head_pole);
```

Main

```
int main (){

node_pole *head_pole = NULL;
election *info = (election*)malloc(sizeof(election));
int i = 0;
```

I create the election and then I insert the node.
I print the election just created and it works (I can read the name of the candidates).

```
createElection(head_pole, info);
insertElection(&head_pole, info);
printf("\nDo you want to visualize your election? Y/N: ");
printf("\n----- Last election created -----\n ");
printf("\nID Election:%s  \nID Elect_user:%s  \nYear:%d\nCounty:%s  \nMax voters:%d", info->ID_election, info->ID_electionUser, info->year, info->county, info->limit_votes); 
printf("\nCandidates' number:%d", info->num_candidates);
for(i = 0; i < info->num_candidates; i++){
    printf("\nCandidates' name [%d]: %s", i+1, ((info + i)->name_candidate));
}
```

This is the result on TERMINAL

> ```
> ID Election:D1  
> ID Elect_user:S1  
> Year:2023 
> County:USA  
> Max voters:5
> Candidates' number:3
> Candidates' name [1]: A1
> Candidates' name [2]: B2
> Candidates' name [3]: C3
> ```

I print the election again but using the fuction printElection.
Here I have the problem. I can't read the name of the candidates but only the first one.

```
printf("\n\t\t\t-ALL-\n\n");    
printElection(head_pole); 

return 0;
}
```

Election printed through function in TERMINAL:

> ```
> ID Election:D1 
> ID Elect_User: S1  
> Year:2023 
> County:USA  
> Max voters:5
> Candidates' number:3
> Candidates' name [1]: A1
> Candidates' name [2]: 
> Candidates' name [3]:
> ```

Functions definiton

```
void createElection(node_pole *head_pole, election *info){

        election *pole = info;    
        int i = 0;

        printf("\nInsert data:  \n Year: ");
        scanf("%d", &pole->year);
        printf(" County:");
        scanf("%s", pole->county);
        printf(" Voters' limit:");
        scanf("%d", &pole->limit_votes);  
        printf("ID_Election: ");         
        scanf("%s", pole->ID_election);
        printf("ID_Election_User: ");         
        scanf("%s", pole->ID_electionUser);
        printf("Candidates' number: ");
        scanf("%d", &pole->num_candidates);
            for(i = 0; i < pole->num_candidates; i++){  
                    printf("\n Candidates' names [%d]:", i+1);
                    scanf("%s", (pole+i)->name_candidate);
            }                
return;
}

void insertElection(node_pole **head_pole, election *info){

        node_pole *newnode = (node_pole*)malloc(sizeof(node_pole));
       
        newnode->voting = *info;
        newnode->next_pole = *head_pole;
        *head_pole = newnode;
return;
}

void printElection(node_pole *head_pole){

    int i;
    node_pole *tmp = head_pole;
    
    if(tmp == NULL){
            printf("\nNo poll in the database.");
            return;
    }
        while(tmp != NULL){
            printf("\n----- Your election ----- ");
            printf("\nID Election:%s \nID Elect_User: %s  \nYear:%d \nCounty:%s  \nMax voters:%d", tmp->voting.ID_election, tmp->voting.ID_electionUser, tmp->voting.year, tmp->voting.county, tmp->voting.limit_votes);
            printf("\nCandidates' number:%d", tmp->voting.num_candidates);
            for(i = 0; i < tmp->voting.num_candidates; i++){
                printf("\nCandidates' name [%d]: %s", i + 1, (tmp+i)->voting.name_candidate);
            }                    
            tmp = tmp->next_pole;
        }
return;
}
```

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? What is `n` in your struct definition? How do you create the list?

Comment: `char name_candidate[n];` There's only space to store the name of **one** candidate. Unseen code could be doing anything...

Comment: @RetiredNinja "const int n = 20" it's the size.

Comment: @Fe2O3 what would you recommend to do?

Comment: Said it already: "_Unseen code could be doing anything_" Post enough code so that a proper assessment and remediation strategy could be found... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Fe2O3 I modified the question. Hope now is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there's currently room for only **one** candidate name (20 - 1 characters long) in an election.

This is wrong:

```
printf("\nCandidates' name [%d]: %s", i+1, ((info + i)->name_candidate));
```

References like the above treat `info` as if it was an array and are equivalent to 
`info[i]->name_candidate`.

`info` is not an array.

Small changes to move this forward (and, hopefully, increase the OP's understanding):

```
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 8 // an arbitrary number

typedef struct pole{
   int year;
   char county[n];
   char ID_election[n];
   char ID_electionUser[n];
   int num_candidates;
   char name_candidate[MAX_CANDIDATES][n]; // 2D array to hold up to 8 x 20 characters
   int limit_votes;
} election;
```

and

```
        printf("# of Candidates: ");
        scanf("%d", &pole->num_candidates);

        if( pole->num_candidates > MAX_CANDIDATES )
            // handle erroneous entry

        for(i = 0; i < pole->num_candidates; i++){  
            printf("\n Candidate's name [%d]:", i+1);
            scanf("%19s", pole->name_candidate[i] );
        }
```

and fixing up the print statement:

```
printf("Candidate name [%d]: %s\n", i+1, info->name_candidate[i]);
```

These changes *should* allow the OP to have some success and move the project forward. It would be worth revisiting this to neither use excessive space for fewer candidates nor impose a limit of 8 candidates. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Finally: each invocation of `scanf()` returns a value that is currently being ignored. Getting user input is fraught with challenges. Another exercise for the reader to increase the robustness of this code.

---

Minor: `typedef struct pole {` and `election *pole = info;` ... Hmmm... Naming a variable with the same name as a datatype is bad practice and bound to lead to confusion. Get things clear in your own mind so that the reader of the code can have it clear in theirs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. 
Regarding scanf, what would you recommend? Reducing the inputs from the user or using another command? 

Thanks for the "naming" advice, I totally agree with new. Trying to have more fantasy on that.

Comment: `scanf()`... At a minimum: `if( scanf( "%d", &var ) != 1 ) { /* handle error */ }` Often, getting/rejecting user input can be 50%+ of the code... Some code actually has separate functions to get `int` or `char *` or `double` values, each validating the user's input is acceptable before returning to the caller... Call this "tech debt" for the working code. Come back to it to make the code more robust! Cheers!